# Script error, in process of converting from VBA- Change Row Height based on Numerical Cell Value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, syntax-error

I've been working on a sheet where I need to set the pixel height of the row based on the value of a cell in that row like this:

[image]

I found a example VBA code I started to use as a reference. Here is the link to that: https://shorturl.at/gBEKM. Original VBA code:

```
Sub rowheight()
'Updateby Extendoffice 20161123
    Dim hgt As Variant
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("please select the data range:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
For Each H In WorkRng
        If H.Value > 15 Then
            hgt = H.Value
            H.EntireRow.Select
            Selection.rowheight = hgt
        End If
    Next H
End Sub
```

This is the sample google apps script code I've been editing down (at the moment the minimum cell height requirement that's integrated in the original would be the next step, still trying to get the basic idea to work first):

```
   function RowHeightByValue() {
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
 sheet.setRowHeights(122,78,[E122:E199])}
```

I am currently getting an error stating:

> *SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' (line 4, file "RowHeightSet.gs")*.

It seems to me that because I'm trying to use variable data within the range rather than a single value it violate the parameters of the command. Any recommendations on a work around?

Comment: I see only one command Sheet.setRowHeights(start row, number of rows, height).  I don't see any commands that allow you to input a range. [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setRowHeights(Integer,Integer,Integer))

Comment: Have you already "studied" the pretty basics of JavaScript, like data types and specially Arrays?

Comment: I'd say I have a rudimentary knowledge, the main program I use for work uses a bastardized, simplified javascript as a base but it doesn't have all the different calls, labels and symbol varients. I've been referring to youtube to try to understand the loop/iteration methods but I obviously don't understand it yet because I am still getting an error. (sorry if I am doing this wrong, I've never used SO before)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a loop or iteration methods like [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) :

```
const row = 122;
sheet.getRange("E122:E199")
  .getValues()
  .forEach(([height], i) => 
     sheet.setRowHeight(row+i, height)
  )
```

[Sheet#setRowHeight](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setrowheightrowposition,-height)